# How to make variables defined outside method to be used inside method in jsr223 sample groovy script

Tags: testing, methods, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

```
def variable1;
def variable2;

def method()
{
  variable1 = someValue;
  variable2 = sameValue;
}

method();
```

I clearly don't want to pass the variables as arguments to functions.

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: You probably need to annotate them with [`@Field`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.9/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Field.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve and what underlying logic is:

1. You can apply [@Field](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Field.html) declaration to your variables:

   [image]
2. You can remove `def` keyword and it will make your variables global

   [image]

References:

- [Groovy language semantics](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html)
- [Groovy Goodness: Variable Scope in Scripts](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-variable-scope-in.html)
- [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)